# failed to generate url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my model

```
class Tourisme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :title, :approximate_ascii => true

   .
   .

end
```

when the title contains  `"?"` or `"/"` and i want to generate an url :

```
 admin_tourisme_path(tourisme)
```

i got an error

```
admin_tourisme_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :id=>#<Tourisme id: 14, title: "title with  ?", description:.............
```

how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

So reading docs (http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md) for friendly_id I found 2 solutions:

1 -  Use `#normalize_friendly_id` in model: 
from doc:

Bye-bye Babosa

Babosa is FriendlyId 3's slugging library.

FriendlyId 4 doesn't use it by default because the most important pieces of it were already accepted into Active Support 3.

However, Babosa is still useful, for example, for idiomatically transliterating Cyrillic (or other language) strings to ASCII. It's very easy to include - just override #normalize_friendly_id in your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def normalize_friendly_id(text)
    text.to_slug.normalize! :transliterations => :russian
  end
end
```

2 -  Use slugged models: http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Slugged